# Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException - The server is busy

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-table-storage

- Language: C#
- Framework: .NET 4.5
- Nuget: WindowsAzure.Storage version 8.0.1

Hi.

I'm seeing a `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException` telling me that "The server is busy" from time to time in the logs of a production site. Does anyone have any experience or pro tips on how to get rid of this behavior. Should I maybe change some setting in the Azure Portal or do something with my code?

The error occurs when the `public static IEnumerable<MessageEntity> Get(string sentTo)` in the example under is called.

Code:

```
private static CloudTable GetMessageTable()
{
    var storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConnectionString"));
    var tableClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();
    var table = tableClient.GetTableReference(CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("MessageTable"));

    try
    {
        if (!table.Exists())
            table.Create();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        // Log err
    }

    return table;
}

public static IEnumerable<MessageEntity> Get(string sentTo)
{
    var table = GetMessageTable();
    var query = new TableQuery<MessageEntity>().Where(TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("PartitionKey", QueryComparisons.Equal, sentTo));

    var result = table.ExecuteQuery(query);
    return result.OrderByDescending(r => r.SentDate);
}
```

Log:

```
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException: The remote server returned an error: (503) Server Unavailable. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (503) Server Unavailable.
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor.ExecuteSync[T](RESTCommand`1 cmd, IRetryPolicy policy, OperationContext operationContext) in c:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\release_dotnet_master\Lib\ClassLibraryCommon\Core\Executor\Executor.cs:line 677
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor.ExecuteSync[T](RESTCommand`1 cmd, IRetryPolicy policy, OperationContext operationContext) in c:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\release_dotnet_master\Lib\ClassLibraryCommon\Core\Executor\Executor.cs:line 604
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.TableQuery`1.<>c__DisplayClass7.<ExecuteInternal>b__6(IContinuationToken continuationToken) in c:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\release_dotnet_master\Lib\ClassLibraryCommon\Table\TableQuery.cs:line 430
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Util.CommonUtility.<LazyEnumerable>d__0`1.MoveNext() in c:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\release_dotnet_master\Lib\Common\Core\Util\CommonUtility.cs:line 322
   at System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source)
   at System.Linq.OrderedEnumerable`1.<GetEnumerator>d__1.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.Count[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate)
   at *** removed ***
Request Information
RequestID:*** removed ***
RequestDate:Tue, 11 Apr 2017 15:30:30 GMT
StatusMessage:Service Unavailable
ErrorCode:ServerBusy
ErrorMessage:The server is busy.
RequestId:*** removed ***
Time:2017-04-11T15:30:31.0229653Z
```

Answer (score 5):

The error suggests that your application is getting throttled by Azure Storage table service.

A good way to investigate these issues is enable Storage Analytic metrics and see if your application is within the storage scalability targets. There are transaction metrics for number of requests and number of throttling errors.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/fileservices/about-storage-analytics-metrics

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-scalability-targets

From the code, consider adding client side retries if you haven't already. I would also generally recommend avoiding PartitionKey scans if you can but it's hard to provide additional comments without knowing the nature of the application.